# How to use oneOf alongside a common sub-schema (V4)

Tags: json, schema, jsonschema

I'm having trouble trying to create a schema that makes use of both oneOf and a common referenced sub-schema, in order to avoid having to duplicate parts of the schema. 
The JSON that the schema should be validating against looks as follows:

```
{
  "createdDate": "2015-01-20T17:10:05Z",
  "createdBy": "testUser",
  "lastModifiedDate": "2015-01-20T17:10:05Z",
  "lastModifiedBy": "testUser",
  "fileUrl": {
    "path": "/path/to/file",
    "fileName": "file.pdf"
  },
  "referenceType": "person",
  "fileType": "certificate",
  "personId": "12345"
}
```

From this, the common part is:

```
{
  "createdDate": "2015-01-20T17:10:05Z",
  "createdBy": "testUser",
  "lastModifiedDate": "2015-01-20T17:10:05Z",
  "lastModifiedBy": "testUser",
  "fileUrl": {
    "path": "/path/to/file",
    "fileName": "file.pdf"
  }
}
```

The remaining 3 fields are always the same in name and all required, but the allowed enum values for them will vary.

So the schema for the remaining 3 could be one of the following:

```
{
"properties": {
    "referenceType": {
        "type": "string",
        "enum": [
            "vehicle"
        ]
    },
    "fileType": {
        "type": "string",
        "enum": [
            "registration document"
        ]
    },
    "vehicleId": {
        "type": "string",
        "pattern": "[^ ]"
    }
},
"required": [
    "vehicleId"
]
}
```

OR

```
{
    "properties": {
        "referenceType": {
            "type": "string",
            "enum": [
                "person"
            ]
        },
        "fileType": {
            "type": "string",
            "enum": [
                "certificate"
            ]
        },
        "personId": {
            "type": "string",
            "pattern": "[^ ]"
        }
    },
    "required": [
        "personId"
    ]
}
```

I can't seem to create a schema whereby I can avoid duplicating the common fields, and have the oneOf, and set additionalProperties to false across the whole schema.
With the below example, trying to set additionalProperties to false causes validation errors. Is it possible to do what I'm trying to do?

```
{
    "type": "object",
    "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-04/schema#",
    "definitions": {
        "commonFile": {
            "properties": {
                "createdDate": {
                    "type": "string",
                    "format": "date-time"
                },
                "createdBy": {
                    "type": "string",
                    "pattern": "[^ ]"
                },
                "lastModifiedDate": {
                    "type": "string",
                    "format": "date-time"
                },
                "lastModifiedBy": {
                    "type": "string",
                    "pattern": "[^ ]"
                },
                "fileUrl": {
                    "type": "object",
                    "additionalProperties": false,
                    "properties": {
                        "path": {
                            "type": "string",
                            "pattern": "[^ ]"
                        },
                        "fileName": {
                            "type": "string",
                            "pattern": "[^ ]"
                        }
                    },
                    "required": [
                        "path",
                        "fileName"
                    ]
                }
            }   
        }
    },
    "oneOf": [{
            "allOf": [
                {"$ref": "#/definitions/commonFile"}, 
                {
                    "properties": {
                        "referenceType": {
                            "type": "string",
                            "enum": [
                                "person"
                            ]
                        },
                        "fileType": {
                            "type": "string",
                            "enum": [
                                "certificate"
                            ]
                        },
                        "personId": {
                            "type": "string",
                            "pattern": "[^ ]"
                        }
                    },
                    "required": [
                        "personId"
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }, {
            "allOf": [
                {"$ref": "#/definitions/commonFile"}, 
                {
                    "properties": {
                        "referenceType": {
                            "type": "string",
                            "enum": [
                                "vehicle"
                            ]
                        },
                        "fileType": {
                            "type": "string",
                            "enum": [
                                "registration document"
                            ]
                        },
                        "vehicleId": {
                            "type": "string",
                            "pattern": "[^ ]"
                        }
                    },
                    "required": [
                        "vehicleId"
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }
    ],
    "required": [
        "createdDate",
        "createdBy",
        "lastModifiedDate",
        "lastModifiedBy",
        "fileUrl",
        "referenceType",
        "fileType"
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recommend *not* setting `additionalProperties` to `false`.  It is usually best just to quietly ignore properties that are not defined.  The following schema is what you would have to do to accomplish your goal.

```
{
  "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-04/schema#",
  "type": "object",
  "properties": {
    "createdDate": { "type": "string", "format": "date-time" },
    "createdBy": { "type": "string", "pattern": "[^ ]" },
    "lastModifiedDate": { "type": "string", "format": "date-time" },
    "lastModifiedBy": { "type": "string", "pattern": "[^ ]" },
    "fileUrl": {
      "type": "object",
      "additionalProperties": false,
      "properties": {
        "path": { "type": "string", "pattern": "[^ ]" },
        "fileName": { "type": "string", "pattern": "[^ ]" }
      },
      "required": ["path", "fileName"]
    },
    "referenceType": { "type": "string" },
    "fileType": { "type": "string" },
    "personId": {},
    "vehicleId": {}
  },
  "additionalProperties": false,
  "anyOf": [
    {
      "properties": {
        "referenceType": { "enum": ["person"] },
        "fileType": { "enum": ["certificate"] },
        "personId": { "type": "string", "pattern": "[^ ]" }
      },
      "required": ["personId"],
      "not" : { "required": ["vehicleId"] }
    },
    {
      "properties": {
        "referenceType": { "enum": ["vehicle"] },
        "fileType": { "enum": ["registration document"] },
        "vehicleId": { "type": "string", "pattern": "[^ ]" }
      },
      "required": ["vehicleId"],
      "not" : { "required": ["personId"] }
    }
  ],
  "required": ["createdDate", "createdBy", "lastModifiedDate", "lastModifiedBy", "fileUrl", "referenceType", "fileType"]
}
```

The first thing I did was remove all the extraneous `allOf`s.  Only one `anyOf` is needed.  I defined the common properties in the main schema.  The variations are described in the `anyOf` clause.

If you set `additionalProperties` to `false`, an additional schema (such as `allOf`, `oneOf`, and `anyOf`) can not introduce new properties.  This means that all properties that are going to be allowed in this schema must be included in the schema that declares `additionalProperties` to be `false`.  That is why I declared `referenceType`, `fileType`, `personId`, and `vechicleId` in the main schema.

The problem now is that `additionalProperties` no longer excludes `vehicleId` when `referenceType` is `person` or `personId` when `referenceType` is `vehicle`.  To make sure this isn't allowed, I added the `not` clauses.

If were you add a third variation, restricting additional properties gets even more difficult.  It's not just adding an additional `referenceType` to the `anyof` schema array.  You also have to add new properties to the main schema and disallow those new types for *all* of the existing `referenceTypes`.  You have to make changes all over the schema instead of just the area that is changing.  This is why setting `additionalProperties` to `false` is generally not the best idea.

Comment: Thanks @Jason, that seems to work. `additionalProperties` certainly doesn't work the way I had expected it to do